# Regex Express to replace every instance of backslash \ with a \u in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, unicode, replace

I really need your help and those that understand regex very well.

How can I replace every instance of single backslash `"\"` with a backslash u `"\u"` inside of a string.

```
var oldstring = "Pneus de contrefa\00E7on. Prot\00E9gez-Vous"
```

Resulting in the following new string:

```
var newstring = "Pneus de contrefa\u00E7on. Prot\u00E9gez-Vous"
```

My intention is to then use the unescape on the new string:

```
unescape(newstring)
```

Comment: where do you get the string from? if you want to use literal strings like this, you have to escape the backslash - `"Pneus de contrefa\\00E7on. Prot\\00E9gez-Vous"` - if you load it from somewhere else and when you print it it looks like you just wrote, then that should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

For this I wouldn't recommend using a regex. I would do the following:

```
var res = str.replace("\\", "\\u");
```

Comment: It's a good approach, but I'm not sure that you obtain a literal backslash with a single backslash in a string.